# React Native 0.57.7 - Android build failed at task :app:mergeReleaseResources

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, bundle-release-js-and-assets

I'm getting an error when running the `./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace` command in my React Native (v0.57.7) project's `android` folder:

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
/Users/steff/Github/iazzu/app/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/package.json: Error: package is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> /Users/steff/Github/iazzu/app/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/package.json: Error: package is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: /Users/steff/Github/iazzu/app/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/package.json: Error: package is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:296)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: /Users/steff/Github/iazzu/app/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/package.json: Error: package is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergingException.throwIfNonEmpty(MergingException.java:152)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:260)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.loadFromFiles(ResourceSet.java:55)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:267)
        ... 42 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 6s
144 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 140 up-to-date
```

When checking the folder `android/build/generated/res/react/release/raw` folder, the `package.json` file is being copied there along with all my other resources (mainly `.json` files).

Also, here are the [android/build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/skizzo/508942ac49d7c38282b68abc7c415fd5) and the [android/app/build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/skizzo/70b5f0561c4daa4fb8647f6f6aabf7e3) files.

What could I possibly do to prevent this weird thing from happening? Just to have said it, I've tried googling for hours now but can't find a solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. React Native v0.60.5 here. Any solution or workaround?

Comment: My problem has importing "package.json" inside app (for retrieving version info). Now using  react-native-device-info instead. (source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23482#issuecomment-490099612)

Comment: @Majoren yes, it‘s exactly what MarcosDanielBaroni said in his solution. There will be a conflict if package.json is imported anywhere in the project, removing all references to it solved the problem on my end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an import of package.json, which is not allowed in the generated build directory.

The easiest way to get the app version is to get it from a lib like `react-native-device-info` :

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'
const currentVersion = DeviceInfo.getVersionSync();
```

This gives me the same number as in package.json (this will give you the native version number of your app).

You can keep your app version in sync between package.json, gradle and Info.plist with a lib like `react-native-version`